# How can I write jquery plugin that works on multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote following functon and I am trying to use that in different elements but it doesn't work.

```
$.fn.sticky = function() {

    var 
        scrollTop           =   $(window).scrollTop();
        replace_class       =   $(this),
        sticky              =   "ceras_sticky_header",
        elementOffset       =   replace_class.offset().top,
        distance            =   (elementOffset - scrollTop),
        leftPositionofImage =   replace_class.offset().left,
        windowWidth         =   $(window).width(),
        elementWidth        =   replace_class.width(),
        rightPosition       =   (windowWidth - leftPositionofImage - elementWidth - 12);

        $(window).scroll(function() {
          if( $(this).scrollTop() > distance) {
            replace_class.addClass(sticky);
            replace_class.css('right',rightPosition);
            replace_class.draggable();
          } else {
            replace_class.removeClass(sticky);
          }
        });
};
```

I want to it to work like:

```
$( ".ancor_controls" ).sticky();
$( ".ancor_controls1" ).sticky();
```

Comment: `$(window).scrollTop();` change it to `$(window).scrollTop(),` see if it works

Comment: @Lixus What's the difference between them?

Comment: with that semicolon he is ending his variable initializations, so the rest of his variables remain undefined for the rest of his script and won't work they way he wants.

Comment: You should post that as an answer. The other variables are defined, but they're not local variables because they're not in the `var` statement.

Comment: Or just VTC as a typo.

Comment: A good IDE would have made this clear, since the variable assignments after `scrollTop` would not be indented the same.

Comment: it worked thank you